# Turning an existing node into a dijit

Tags: dojo

what is the best way to turn an EXISTING dom node (say we a div element) into a dijit of a given class (with keeping all element attributes)? I tried to set a dojoType attribute on the node to a given dijit class, but it doesn't seem to work. I am using dojo 1.6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

during runtime or as a part of the page bootstrap (with control over html)?

node-hierachy might change slightly if you use the markup parser, which is what kicks in when you set a dojoType. To avoid that, you would need to create a programmatic widget and append it as a child of said DOMNode. So, you have three options basically

1. using the dojo config parseOnLoad:true and setting dojoType attribute in the source-html
2. at runtime, manually call parser on your node after setting the dojoType
3. at runtime, create the class via programmatic api and use `.placeAt(domNode)`

Say, you would want to extend a node with contentpane layout capeabilities (if not a layout widget, there's no saying what will happen to innerHTML, it depends on each widget's markupfactory):

#### while using markup parser approach:

```
<div id="getme" style="background-color:blue">
  Contents
</div>
<script>
  var n = dojo.byId('getme');               n.dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane";
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane"); dojo.require("dojo.parser");
  dojo.parser.parse(n);
</script>
```

#### Or a programmatic approach:

```
<div id="getme" style="background-color:blue"></div>
<script>
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
  var w = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({ href: 'ajaxContents.html' });
  w.startup();
  w.placeAt('getme');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant it during the runtime, say we as an onclick event. Option 2. answers it, I was not aware that I can call the parser manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is also simple way via passing the node into the dijit constructor:

```
var nodeToDigitize = dojo.query('#mynode')[0];
new myDijit({prop1: val1, ...}, nodeToDigitize);
```